# Windows 10 File Recovery

Tags: recovery

How do I recover deleted Excel files?  I have tried to find backup but cant and have loaded Windows File recovery but cant understand how to issue instructions using it - I am not an experienced programmer. help please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you don't want issue command and using parameters try using it with a GUI: https://www.winfr.org/

Comment: File recovery is no an absolute process, what I mean by that, if the data of the deleted file is overwritten then the file cannot be restored.  If you have used the appropriate tools to restore the deleted file, and those tools could not find the file fragments of the deleted file, then the file CANNOT be restored.

Comment: Have you looked in the Recycle Bin ?

Comment: Do you have OneDrive on your computer and running? Have you looked in your recycle bin? Backups only work if you've actually set them up to run.

Comment: If files were deleted from SSD it's 99% futile anyway, see https://youtu.be/NyLQbxnPurc

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Recuva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recuva) before which serves most cases.

Here, deletion means when the file is no longer in your filesystem, i.e., when you (a) empty the Recycle Bin, (b) have disabled the Recycle Bin, or (c) force delete a file with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to bypass the Recycle Bin.

If your file is still in your Recycle Bin then just recover from there.

However, once a file is deleted, the filesystem will mark the space used by that file as available, thus new data can overwrite that space. Therefore, the best thing to do once you realize you mis-deleted a file, is to stop using the partition/volume (e.g., C:, D:) that the file was located.

If you keep writing to the partition, or if it is the system partition that Windows will keep writing to it anyway, then it is highly likely that your file is gone forever.

There is a reason why Recycle Bin exists. If you do not have good habit of backing up your important files timely, better leverage what your system provides you.